# Get sender email address with Python IMAP

Tags: python, email, imap

I have this python IMAP script, but my problem is that, every time I want to get the sender's email address, (From), I always get the sender's first name followed by their email address:

Example:

```
Souleiman Benhida <souleb@gmail.com>
```

How can i just extract the email address (`souleb@gmail.com`)

I did this before, in PHP:

```
    $headerinfo = imap_headerinfo($connection, $count)
    or die("Couldn't get header for message " . $count . " : " . imap_last_error());
$from = $headerinfo->fromaddress;
```

But, in python I can only get the full name w/address, how can I get the address alone? I currently use this:

```
    typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
mail = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
headers = HeaderParser().parsestr(data[0][1]) 
message = parse_message(mail)  #body
org = headers['From']
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just one more step, using [email.utils](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parseaddr):

> `email.utils.parseaddr(address)`
>
> Parse address – which should be the value of some address-containing field such as To or Cc – into its constituent realname and email address parts. Returns a tuple of that information, unless the parse fails, in which case a 2-tuple of ('', '') is returned.

*Note: originally referenced `rfc822`, which is now deprecated.*

Comment: +1 You may also wish to mention that rfc822 has been deprecated since 2.3, and that parseaddr's new home is email.utils.parseaddr.

Comment: @Soule: Yes.  Here are [the python 2.6 docs for email.utils.parseaddr](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parseaddr).

Answer (score 0):

```
to = email.utils.parseaddr(msg['cc'])
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

My external lib https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools
let you work with mail instead read IMAP specifications.

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, A

# get all emails from INBOX folder
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'pwd', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    for msg in mailbox.fetch(A(all=True)):
        print(msg.date, msg.from_, msg.to, len(msg.text or msg.html))
```

msg.from_, msg.to - parsed addresses, like: 'Sender@ya.ru'

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like the existing solutions so I decided to make a sister library for [my email sender](https://github.com/Miksus/red-mail) called [Red Box](https://github.com/Miksus/red-box).

Here is how to search and process emails including getting the `from` address:

```
from redbox import EmailBox

# Create email box instance
box = EmailBox(
    host="imap.example.com", 
    port=993,
    username="me@example.com",
    password="<PASSWORD>"
)

# Select an email folder
inbox = box["INBOX"]

# Search and process messages
for msg in inbox.search(unseen=True):

    # Process the message
    print(msg.from_)
    print(msg.to)
    print(msg.subject)
    print(msg.text_body)
    print(msg.html_body)

    # Flag the email as read/seen
    msg.read()
```

I also wrote [extensive documentation](https://red-box.readthedocs.io/) for it. It also has query language that fully supports nested logical operations.