# Parse email address only without name

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, email-address

When using Email library, is there a way to get the internet email address without the name, so for `"Jon Doe"<jon.doe@gmail.comm>`, how can I just get `jon.doe@gmail.com`.

I am loading a mime message from file with `email.message_from_binary_file()` and then getting the FROM header by accessing the `"from"` key:

```
message = email.message_from_binary_file()
from_header = message["from"]
```

I can't seem to find in Email docs how I can parse this down further to just the email address?

EDIT:
Current solution that I don't think is very elegant and might be error-prone is to do a regex likes so:

```
from_header = re.findall('\S+@\S+', message["from"])[0][1:-1]
```

So get the first (and only) element from regex list and then remove the opening and closing brackets (`"<"` & `">"`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get sender email address with Python IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174770/get-sender-email-address-with-python-imap)

Comment: @BallpointBen Yes, that is exactly what I needed. Thank you.